# Help Center page about deleting an account isn't clear about steps required

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-accounts

I just had a user who I believe was confused by the deletion process. This is the current Help Center [page on account deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account):

[image: Current Help Center page on deleting an account]

The way the item about Contacting the staff is listed, it could easily be interpreted as an additional option, not a required step.

This ambiguity could be solved by forgoing the bullet points, and simply including the instructions in the single line about the image.

> Edit the "About Me" section of your profile to say "please delete me", then contact us to request deletion.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps numbering the items or reordering the items so that the "contact us" part comes first would be better. The "edit your profile" step does tend to dominate because of the screen shot.

Comment: Oh, yes; that would also be an excellent option.